# Manatee.Trello: Simple CRUD App for Updating Cards

Tags: manatee.trello

I need to develop a simple CRUD console app to update a list of Trello cards from a CSV file. I'll run the app in TaskScheduler every night. I've installed @gregsdennis Manatee.Trello packages (impressive code!) but cannot find a single (complete example) of anything like this anywhere. All I've managed to do is auth in with app key and tokedn.

Is there a resource out there that shows simple (full) examples of how to get started? @gregsdennis—the C# libraries are extensive and obviously well thought out—I just need a jump start to get me going. Thanks to all in advance!

Answer (score -1):

Here's the documentation site: https://gregsdennis.github.io/Manatee.Trello/usage/getting-started.html

Comment: Why'd I get downvoted on this?  OP asked for "a jump start."  That's precisely what the documentation gives.